# expectObservable().toBe() only receives last value of stream

Tags: rxjs, jasmine, rxjs-marbles, rxjs-test-scheduler

I want to test a service that uses internally a `BehaviorSubject` to hold the state and exposes `Observable`s with a `distinctUntilChanged()` in the pipe. When I run the following test, than the actual steam that is compared with my expectations only 'contains' the last value. What do I have to understand to fix that?

```js
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';
import { distinctUntilChanged } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { TestScheduler } from 'rxjs/testing';

describe('My exposed stream', () => {
  let testScheduler;

  beforeEach(() => {
    testScheduler = new TestScheduler((actual, expected) => {
      expect(actual).toEqual(expected);
    });
  });

  it('does not propagate if the current value equals the last one', () => {
    testScheduler.run(({ expectObservable }) => {
      const internalStream$ = new BehaviorSubject<string>(null);
      const exposedStream$ = internalStream$.pipe(distinctUntilChanged());

      expectObservable(exposedStream$).toBe('012', [null, 'foo', 'bar']);

      internalStream$.next('foo');
      internalStream$.next('foo');
      internalStream$.next('bar');
    });
  });
});
```

Result:

```
Expected $.length = 1 to equal 3.
Expected $[0].notification.value = 'bar' to equal null.
Expected $[1] = undefined to equal Object({ frame: 1, notification: Notification({ kind: 'N', value: 'foo', error: undefined, hasValue: true }) }).
Expected $[2] = undefined to equal Object({ frame: 2, notification: Notification({ kind: 'N', value: 'bar', error: undefined, hasValue: true }) }).
```

You can run and modify the code here:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-moydq7?file=test.ts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My code had 2 issues:

1. I needed to catch the events with a `ReplySubject` (Thank you, @AliF50)
2. The correct marble notation to verify the behavior is `(012)` instead if `012`, because the 3 events are sent within the same time frame synchronously.

Here is my solution. Still very cumbersome and if you are aware of better ways, please let me know.

```js
import { BehaviorSubject, ReplaySubject } from 'rxjs';
import { distinctUntilChanged } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { TestScheduler } from 'rxjs/testing';

describe('My exposed stream', () => {
  let testScheduler;

  beforeEach(() => {
    testScheduler = new TestScheduler((actual, expected) => {
      expect(actual).toEqual(expected);
    });
  });

  it('does not propagate if the current value equals the last one', () => {
    testScheduler.run(({ expectObservable }) => {

      // given
      const internalStream$ = new BehaviorSubject<string>(null);
      const exposedStream$ = internalStream$.pipe(distinctUntilChanged());

      const observedValues$ = new ReplaySubject<string>();
      exposedStream$.subscribe(observedValues$);

      // when
      internalStream$.next('foo');
      internalStream$.next('foo');
      internalStream$.next('bar');

      // then
      expectObservable(observedValues$).toBe('(012)', [null, 'foo', 'bar']);
    });
  });
});
```

You can play around with it here:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-sa1n8v?file=test.ts

Answer (score 1):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/62773431/7365461, I think that post can answer your question.

That being said, I would test it like so (without the `testScheduler`):

```
it('does not propagate if the current value equals the last one', () => {
  const internalStream$ = new BehaviorSubject<string>(null);
  const exposedStream$ = internalStream$.pipe(distinctUntilChanged());
  
  let subscribeCount = 0;
  const subscribeValues = [];
  exposedStream$.subscribe(value => {
    if (subscribeCount > 3) {
      fail();
    }

    subscribeValues.push(value);
  });

  internalStream$.next('foo');
  internalStream$.next('foo');
  internalStream$.next('bar');
  
  expect(subscribeValues).toEqual([null, 'foo', 'bar']);
});
```

**Edit**

It seems like our syntax for `expectObservable` is a bit wrong, I don't have experience with `expectObservable` though. Check this out, it works in the link you have provided me:

```
import { BehaviorSubject, ReplaySubject } from 'rxjs';
import { distinctUntilChanged } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { TestScheduler } from 'rxjs/testing';

describe('My exposed stream', () => {
  let testScheduler;

  beforeEach(() => {
    testScheduler = new TestScheduler((actual, expected) => {
      expect(actual).toEqual(expected);
    });
  });

  it('does not propagate if the current value equals the last one', () => {
    testScheduler.run(({ expectObservable }) => {
      const internalStream$ = new BehaviorSubject<string>(null);
      const exposedStream$ = internalStream$.pipe(distinctUntilChanged());

      const observedValues$ = new ReplaySubject<string>();
      exposedStream$.subscribe(observedValues$);
      expectObservable(observedValues$).toBe('(abc)', {'a': null, 'b': 'foo', 'c': 'bar' });

      internalStream$.next('foo');
      internalStream$.next('foo');
      internalStream$.next('bar');
    });
  });
});
```

As for as the assertions not traversing inside of the `subscribe`, I understand and you're right. I have two defense strategies for this. One is using the `done` callback of `jasmine` and the other is using `failSpecWithNoExpectations` of `jasmine`. Check out this link https://testing-angular.com/angular-testing-principles/ towards the end on how to do it. This will fail a test if it has no expectations or no expectations were travelled/traversed.

For the `done` callback, you can do:

```
it('does stuff', done => {
  myObservable$.subscribe(value => {
    expect(value).toBe('abc');
    // call done to tell jasmine you're done with this test
    // if this done is not called, the test will hang and fail
    done();
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you, @AliF50 for your support!

I also cannot get it run with a `ReplaySubject`:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-wdbzdp?file=test.ts

Comment: About testing without `TestScheduler`: the issue is that our tests would then depend on the scheduler that is used within the code that we are testing. In your example the test would fail if an `AsyncScheduler` would be used, which is fine. But in most cases, the tests would just succeed, because the assertions are placed within the subscription callbacks and those callbacks would never be called. So you would skip tests without even noticing it. For me it seems more safe to define: All tests with streams use the `TestScheduler` than "no assertions in subscriptions". But let's see if it works.

Comment: I could get it run with the `ReplaySubject`. The issue was that in the marble notation `012` had to be `(012)` because they are dispatched synchroniously within the same time frame.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-sa1n8v?file=test.ts

Still this solution is a bit cumbersome and I would love to have a more straightforward way.

Comment: Yes, you're right, I edited my answer to do it that way. I understand it is cumbersome. Check out my edit, I have shown you two strategies that I use for `Observable` testing. I remember using `jasmine-marbles` before but I didn't like it because you can easily mess up the dashes (--).