# Testing BehaviorSubject with RxJS Marble

Tags: rxjs, jasmine, jasmine-marbles, rxjs-marbles

I have a problem with testing BehaviorSubject using rxjs marble.

Minimal reproduction:

```
scheduler.run(({ expectObservable }) => {
    const response$ = new BehaviorSubject(1);
    expectObservable(response$).toBe('ab', { a: 1, b: 2 });
    response$.next(2);
});
```

Error:

```
Expected $.length = 1 to equal 2.
Expected $[0].notification.value = 2 to equal 1.
```

In my case response$ is returned from some service's method.
How can I test it?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try switching the order and see if that helps?

```
scheduler.run(({ expectObservable }) => {
    const data$ = new ReplaySubject<number>();
    const response$ = new BehaviorSubject(1);
    response$.subscribe(num => data$.next(num));
    response$.next(2);
    expectObservable(data$).toBe('(ab)', { a: 1, b: 2 });
});
```

I think with the `expectObservable`, that's when the observable is subscribed and tested.

**Edit**

You need to use `ReplaySubject` instead of `BehaviorSubject` because `BehaviorSujbect` only returns the last emission of the `Subject`. Check out my edit above. I got inspired by this answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62773431/7365461.

Comment: The result is the same, still throws error.

Comment: Ok, check out my answer above. Try to use a `ReplaySubject` because a `BehaviorSubject` only emits the last value.

Comment: I want to get the last value, that's why I'm using BehaviorSubject. Using ReplaySubject(1) like this would produce the same error.

const response$ = new ReplaySubject(1);
response$.next(1);
expectObservable(response$).toBe('ab', { a: 1, b: 2 });
response$.next(2);

Comment: Ok, sorry, I am not sure.